# Convert render() of class component to functional component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to convert class based component to functional component and almost finished it but got stck in the render() conversion
Can some one help me with that
Below is my code

```
render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap(props => (
      <GoogleMap
      
        defaultZoom={8}
        center={this.state.center}
      >
      {this.state.addNewZone === true && (
        <DrawingManager
          defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
            },
            polygonOptions: { editable: true, draggable: true }
          }}
          onPolygonComplete={value => getPaths(value)}
        />)}

        {this.state.polygon !== null &&
          this.state.polygon.map((poly, index) => (
            <Polygon
              ref={ref => {
                this._polyRef(ref);
              }}
              paths={poly.coord}
              onMouseDown={() => {
                this._onMousedown(index);
              }}
              editable
            />
          ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.polygonData.map((zone, index) => (
          <button
            id={zone.area}
            onClick={() => this.zoneBtnClicked(zone, index)}
          >
            {zone.area}
          </button>
        ))}
        <button onClick={() => this.newZoneBtnClicked()}>Add New Zone</button>
        <GoogleMapExample/>
      </div>
)
export default Map;
```

For more reference code can also be viewed in here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoneshow-s3qvyj?file=Map.js

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am not knowing how to convert this render() to functional component

Comment: Get rid of the `render() {` and `}`, so it returns the html directly inside the functional component, and start to resolve errors from that point on. ie `function Comp() { ...; return (<div>...</div>); }`, most likely anything that starts with `this`.

Answer (score 1):

I have converted your code to the functional-based component in the file you mentioned in the question please find the below link:-

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Polygon } from 'react-google-maps';
import { DrawingManager } from 'react-google-maps/lib/components/drawing/DrawingManager';
import data from './data.json';

let polygonRef = [];
const Map = () => {
  const [drawingControlEnabled, setDrawingControlEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [polygon, setPolygon] = useState(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
  const [polygonData, setPolygonData] = useState(data);
  const [zoneIndex, setZoneIndex] = useState(null);
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 });
  const [addNewZone, setAddNewZone] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('original value of your json data', polygonData);
  }, []);

  const zoneBtnClicked = (zone, index) => {
    console.log('current zone', zone);
    setPolygon(zone.polygon);
    setCenter(zone.polygon[0].coord[2]);
    setZoneIndex(index);
  };

  //function will be called when the add new zone button will be clicked. You can put your code on how you can pass new details of the Zone base on your json data.
  const newZoneBtnClicked = () => {
    setAddNewZone(true);
    //this will set the value of addNewZone state that will make the Drawing Manager visible.
  };

  const _onMousedown = (ref) => {
    //get the reference of the polygon then used the ref as it's index so that you can get the specific polygon
    const polygon = polygonRef[ref].getPath();
    console.log(polygon);
    //add event listeners for the polygon changes and pass the polygon as parameter to the function you need, you also need to pass the ref (or index)
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'set_at', () => {
      _getPolygonNewPaths(polygon, ref);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'insert_at', () => {
      _getPolygonNewPaths(polygon, ref);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'remove_at', () => {
      _getPolygonNewPaths(polygon, ref);
    });
  };

  const _getPolygonNewPaths = (polygon, ref) => {
    let polygonPaths = [];
    polygon.getArray().forEach((path) => {
      const line = {
        lat: path.lat(),
        lng: path.lng(),
      };
      polygonPaths.push(line);
    });
    //this is the new polygon paths which includes what you editted
    console.log('new polygonpaths', polygonPaths);
    //you will see the current value of that polygon paths in your state
    console.log(
      'current polygonpaths from state',
      polygonData[zoneIndex].polygon[ref].coord
    );
    //put this current value of your polygonData to a variable holder
    const newPolygon = polygonData;
    //change the value of the polygon path to the variable that holds yout current polygonData
    newPolygon[zoneIndex].polygon[ref].coord = polygonPaths;
    //This is now the value of your changed polygonData
    console.log('changed polygon data in variable hiolder', newPolygon);
    //now change the polygon Data state to the changed polygonData
    setPolygonData(newPolygon);

    console.log('changed Polygon Data in state', polygonData);
  };

  //function that will put all the polygon ref in the array since polygons will be iterated base on the json data
  const _polyRef = (ref) => {
    polygonRef.push(ref);
  };

  const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap((props) => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} center={center}>
      {addNewZone === true && (
        <DrawingManager
          defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON}
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON],
            },
            polygonOptions: { editable: true, draggable: true },
          }}
          onPolygonComplete={(value) => getPaths(value)}
        />
      )}

      {polygon !== null &&
        polygon.map((poly, index) => (
          <Polygon
            ref={(ref) => {
              _polyRef(ref);
            }}
            paths={poly.coord}
            onMouseDown={() => {
              _onMousedown(index);
            }}
            editable
          />
        ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      {polygonData.map((zone, index) => (
        <button id={zone.area} onClick={() => zoneBtnClicked(zone, index)}>
          {zone.area}
        </button>
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => newZoneBtnClicked()}>Add New Zone</button>
      <GoogleMapExample
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/zoneshow-uatpxw?file=Map.js